# Average commute time

Tags: problem-solving

Roads in town looks like this:

[image]

Where $t=45$ means the path takes 45 minutes, and
$t=\frac{N}{100}$ means the path takes as many minutes as the number of drivers who chose that path divided by $100$. For example, if $200$ drivers go from home to B, that path takes
$\frac{200}{100}=2$ minutes.

Every day, $4000$ drivers leave home, heading for work. Whenever there is a choice between two paths, every driver will choose the shortest path.

What is the average commute time, in minutes, from home to work?

**Solution:** Initially both the path costs same time (N=0, hence 45 minutes). Now since A is taken by one driver it costs (45+1/100) So next driver will take path B which has still t=45+0/100, therefore he will take that path. So on so forth,

$$ T(A) = 45+45+1/100+45+2/100+...+45+1999/100$$

T(B) will be same as T(A).
Therefore solving this summation we get Avg commute time as **54.995 minutes .**

What's wrong in this analysis?
P.S. this question is form Expii-Travel

**Edit:** So correct answer is 65, 45+ N/100 i.e. $$T(A)=T(B)=45+2000/100=65$$
The problem is poorly stated and assumed reader to assume somethings. But if asked to do analysis in the above stated manner then would it be correct?

Comment: What is $T(A)$? Also, what is the value that you are trying to calculate?

Comment: Looks good, what makes you think this is incorrect?

Comment: @5xum T(A) is sum of time of every driver passed through point A. We can also take average there like did in edited. **We want to calculate the average time taken by drivers.**

Comment: @QC_QAOA the site is giving incorrect answer. Updated thier assumption in edit.

Comment: I think you and the website are making different assumptions leading to different solutions.

You are defining $N$ as the number of drivers on the given road at the specific time a new driver is about to go onto the road and you assume that drivers go onto the road one by one.

The website is either defining $N$ as the eventual (total) number of drivers on the road i.e. $2000$, or is assuming that all the drivers go onto the road at the same time.

Comment: Yes exactly, Assuming drivers go one by one is my solution correct then?

Comment: Yes, assuming drivers go one by one your way looks good.